# Write links to all linked pages with current page in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is there some mediawiki tag or extension, which allow to write on current page links to all pages, which contains links to current page?

Comment: I don't think so. [Some special pages can be transcluded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion#Special_pages), but not `Special:WhatLinksHere`.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all the pages that link to a specific article by going to the `Special:WhatLinksHere/MyPageTitle` page in your Wiki. Then, just edit your article and add the relevant links.
Hope this helps.